# Change hex to string

Tags: go

I'm going through the Golang tutorial, and I am on this part

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("My favorite number is", rand.Seed)
}
```

This returns `My favorite number is 0xb1c20`

I have been reading on https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed but I'm still a bit confused as to how have it instead of show the hex show a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`math/rand.Seed`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) is a function; you are printing the function's location in memory. You probably meant to do something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(234) // replace with your seed value, or set the seed based off
                   // of the current time
    fmt.Println("My favorite number is", rand.Int())
}
```

Comment: So the ```rand.Seed(234)``` stored in memory and then convereted into a int when you call the ```int()``` on the rand function again?

Comment: @nadermx: Not totally. [This article](http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/Random/Random.html) might explain a little more about what is going on.